# Context variable for Jekyll in Netlify

Tags: jekyll, netlify

Jekyll to detect the build waits the `JEKYLL_ENV` variable: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/environments/

Netlify sets the `CONTEXT` variable: https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/?_ga=2.28134843.62454114.1555938051-984068889.1555938051#environment-variables

As result Jekyll doesn't see that build i

Answer (score 1):

Netlify's `CONTEXT` variable is not intended to be the same as Jekyll's `JEKYLL_ENV`.  So, you'll want to set `JEKYLL_ENV` separately, probably using [netlify.toml](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/)?  Something like this may work:

```
# this will be the default for every branch other than the production branch
[build.environment]
  JEKYLL_ENV="development"
# only for production branch, override to production
[context.production.environment]
  JEKYLL_ENV="production"
```

Comment: I tried the first half `[build.environment]` `JEKYLL_ENV="netlify"` and it works, although I expected it to raise a syntax error, as the the usual syntax is `[build]` `environment = { JEKYLL_ENV = "netlify" }` with curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and sorted it by adding `JEKYLL_ENV` in the environment variables in Netlify settings page. No need to add a toml file.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully tested three different ways to set the `JEKYLL_ENV` environment variable, which can then be accessed in Liquid templates as `jekyll.environment`:

1. `netlify.toml`: Set the env var in the build command directly

   ```
   # global context
   [build]
     publish = "_site/"
     command = "JEKYLL_ENV=\"netlify\" jekyll build"
   ```
2. `netlify.toml`: Set a build environment

   ```
   # global context
   [build]
     publish = "_site/"
     command = "jekyll build"
     environment = { JEKYLL_ENV = "netlify" }
   ```
3. `netlify.toml`: Run a custom build script

   ```
   # global context
   [build]
     publish = "_site/"
     command = "sh netlify.sh"
   ```

   `netlify.sh`: Set the env var in the build command

   ```
   JEKYLL_ENV="netlify" jekyll build
   ```